# Conky manager v2.72 stuck on searching directories

Tags: gnome, unity, themes, git, conky

A few days ago I joined Linux by installing UBUNTU to my HP laptop.
I used Some themes and used CONKY to get a date time widget to my desktop screen, but now conky isn't running. I visited its Git page where it suggested to install CONKY MANAGER 2. I installed it but my theme wasn't listedthere. GIT page suggested that I should change the location to .config/conky/  I did it and not when I refresh it is stuck on searching directories for 6 hours.

I installed Azha theme: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1847815

Theam GIT page: https://github.com/closebox73/applying-theme

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Can you please edit your question to include the release of Ubuntu that you're using? Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but managed to fix it with the following steps:

1. In ConkyManager, select Application Settings i.e. wrench/spanner icon, upper right corner.
2. Under Locations, make sure that the Theme Directory is set to ~/.conky
3. Optional: Copy the widget/theme that you want to use to the ~/.conky folder. This way, Conky/ConkyManager will only have to search through that one folder for widgets/themes.
4. Remove any additional folders under "Additional locations to search for Conky themes".
5. Delete/remove any additional widgets/themes (folders) that you're not going to use from the ~/.conky folder i.e. installed by Conky by default.

Note: I think Conky (or Conky Manager) adds ~/. under "Additional locations to search for Conky themes" during installation by default, which makes Conky/ConkyManager search through more folders for widgets/themes than you require. I removed ~/.

Note2: You can add as many or as few folders under "Additional locations to search for Conky themes" as you like, but as mentioned, I suggest simply moving/copying the widget/theme that you're going to use to the ~/.conky folder so that Conky/ConkyManager only has have to search through that one folder.

Before I completed these steps,, I had Conky widgets/themes in multiple directories (as backup). With ~/. set under "Additional locations to search for Conky themes", Conky/ConkyManager searched through ALL folders, even those stored in Home, DropBox, Nextcloud, etc. which took a significant amount of time.

Hope that helps. Let me know if you have any issues.